# What does 'do not insist that' means in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> We also **do not insist that** you type your solutions. As usual, you are responsible for ensuring your submitted solutions are easily legible.

After some search on internet, I found following similar sentenses

- do not wish that
- do not contend that
- do not argue that
- do not allege that
- do not suggest
- do not say that
- do not recommend that

Does this means it's better to type the solution, but we don't have to type it; or it means not recommend to type the solution?

Comment: It means that they'd really like typed submissions but will accept anything that's as legible.

Comment: I see, thanks, but my confusion was suggest/insist/recommend seems have same meaning, but how **not insist** here suddenly become to 'like' or recommend

Comment: 'do not insist that' = 'do not demand that'.

Comment: Indeed, as @EdwinAshworth says. If I _suggest_ something, I am telling you that it is a possibility. I probably won't do so if I think it's a bad choice, but I may do so if I know nothing about it as a choice. If I _recommend_ something, I am saying that I think it is a good choice. If I _insist_ on something, I am telling you that you must use it.

Comment: _Insist_ does _not_ mean the same as _suggest_ or _recommend_.

Comment: you did some searches on the internet. Did you also look in a dictionary?  That’s the first place you should look when wondering what a words means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"It's better to type the solution, but we don't have to type it" is the correct interpretation. "Do not insist" in this context means that it is not required of you, but given the requirement that "your submitted solutions are easily legible," typing is preferable because it generally improves legibility.